# Non-resolvable parent POM

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, maven

**Error**:

> Non-resolvable parent POM for com.shutterfly.application:tests

`pom.xml` file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <parent> 
        <groupId>com.shutterfly.application</groupId>
        <artifactId>sfly</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent> 
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>tests</artifactId> 
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>tests</name> 
    <modules>        
        <module>shutterfly</module> 
    </modules>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems listed in the error description:

```
Could not find artifact com.shutterfly.application:sfly:pom:1.16.2-SNAPSHOT
```

To resolve the first, you need to verify that this SNAPSHOT version of the sfly application is in your maven repository. 
For more information on repositories you can [see the documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html)

The second problem is:

```
'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ com.shutterfly.application:tests:[unknown-version]
```

You need to verify the pom for your current application, the "tests" one.
The problem area should be underlined in red, and most likely is version mismatch with your parent pom.

Answer (score 0):

The creator of the original pom had a particular directory structure in mind - the path to the parent pom is hardcoded.

You have the project in different structure, hence the parent pom cannot be found when it originally was...